# Recursive/Exploded uri variable with restlet

Tags: restlet

Does Restlet support exploded path variable (reference to URI Template RFC)? 
An example would be /documents{/path*} where path can be for example "a/b/c/d/e".
This syntax doesn't seem to work with Restlet.

I'm creating a folder navigation api and I can have variable path depth, but I'm trying to have only one resource on the server side to handle all the calls. Is this something I can do with Restlet? I suppose I could create a custom router but if there is another way to do this I would like to know.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to support this using matching modes.

For example:

```
myRouter.attach("/documents{path}", 
    MyResource.class).setMatchingMode(Template.START_WITH);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the following
myRouter.attach("/documents/{path}", MyResource.class).setMatchingMode(Template.START_WITH);

Now I do get inside the resource GET method, but if I request the value of the path variable, I only get the first part (for example, /documents/a/b/c, path returns "a".) I use getRequest().getAttributes().get("path") to retrieve the value. Am I doing something wrong ?

Mathieu